# Explicit destructor in templated context

Tags: c++, templates, destructor

I want to explicitly destroy a `vector` in a templated context. The following works for me (GNU C++ 4.3, 4.4 and Clang++ 1.1):

```
template <typename T>
void destroy_vector_owner(VectorOwner<T> *obj)
{
    obj->v.~vector();
    // further cleanup by Python API functions omitted
}
```

while it fails on Mac OS X v10.5's `g++` (`i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1`) with

```
expected class-name before ‘(’ token
```

If I change it to

```
obj->v.~vector<T>();
```

the code fails to compile with G++, but Clang can still handle it. Which is the correct idiom? Are any of these compilers known to be broken in this regard?

**Update**: the definition of `VectorOwner` is

```
template <typename T>
struct VectorOwner {
  PyObject_HEAD
  std::vector<T> v;
};
```

This is a Python object that has to keep an `std::vector` alive. I admit that the construct is slightly dangerous, but I need the compact storage, amortized O(1) `push_back` and the ability to steal another vector's contents with the `swap` member.

Comment: Can you post the definition of `VectorOwner`?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do this? Why not just let the object go out of scope? If that's not an option for some odd reason, use some kind of smart pointer like `boost::shared_ptr` or something.

Comment: Wait, how did you even initialize `obj.v` when it isn't a pointer? Did you dereference the result of a new expression?

Comment: Anyway, I'm not even sure statically allocated objects are even meant to be deleted like that... Wouldn't it mess up your stack?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: posted the definition. The vector is initialized with placement `new` after `VectorOwner` is allocated with `malloc` (nothing I can do about that).

Comment: Ohhh, Python... Take a look at Boost.Python. It'll make your life a lot easier. :)

Comment: @Paul: depending on Boost is not an option for this project. Cython is the Python/C++ binding we already use, but it won't handle a C++ class as a non-pointer member and thus introduce an extra level of indirection that I don't want.

Comment: @larsmans: Can you post the statement with your `new` expression, too? How do you prevent the default constructor to run on `obj.v`? This looks a little bogus to me.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: `new (&owner->v) std::vector<T>();` immediately after `VectorOwner<T> *owner` has been allocated with `PyObject_New`, which calls `malloc`, and a check for `NULL` return from that function. The default constructor does not run twice because of the `malloc`.

Comment: I see, fair enough. Seems like the problem is just due to compiler bugs then. (For instance, both versions that you posted work in GCC 4.6.1.) Very interesting question for sure!

Comment: @larsmans: Interesting ... does the error persist if destroy_vector_owner() becomes a VectorOwner's method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first answer was wrong actually, litb pointed me into the right direction. The right answer is
that both syntaxes are correct:

---

### Destructor call syntax.

The syntax for an explicit destructor call is described in `12.4 Destructors`:

```
12  In an explicit destructor call, the destructor name appears
    as a ˜ followed by a type-name that names the destructor’s 
    class type. The invocation of a destructor is subject to the
    usual rules for member functions (9.3) [...]
```

`type-name` can be found in `7.1.5.2 Simple type specifiers`:

```
type-name:
    class-name
    enum-name
    typedef-name
```

`class-name` is described in `9. Classes`:

```
class-name:
    identifier
    template-id
```

So a destructor call is, simplified, one of the following

```
foo.~typedef-name ()
foo.~identifier   ()
foo.~template-id  ()
```

We neither have a typedef-name here, nor a simple identifier, so only `foo.~template-id()` is left
for us.

---

### Compiler's assumption on destructor call with template-arguments.

We also find in `14. Templates`

```
3 After name lookup (3.4) finds that a name is a template-name,
  if this name is followed by a <, the < is always taken as the
  beginning of a template-argument-list and never as a name
  followed by the less-than operator.
```

So the compiler must assume in your example that the `<` is the beginning
of a template-argument-list.

Also, if your destructor would be a template (...), then

```
4   When the name of a member template specialization appears 
    after . or -> in a postfix-expression, or after nested-name-specifier
    in a qualified-id, and the postfix-expression or qualified-id explicitly
    depends on a template-parameter (14.6.2), the member template name must
    be prefixed by the keyword template. Otherwise the name is assumed to 
    name a non-template.
```

So because you did not prefix your destructor call `f.~foo<int>` with template, i.e.
like `f.template ~foo<int>`, the compiler must assume that your destructor
is NOT a template.

#### Backtrack.

Further,

```
6   A template-id that names a class template specialization
    is a class-name (clause 9).
```

So `~foo<int>` names your template specialization `foo<int>` and therefore is a `class-name`,
a `class-name` is by the grammar rules a `type-name`, and a `~` followed by a `typename` is
a destructor call. Therefore

```
foo<int> f;
f.~foo<int>(); // valid
```

---

### Destructor call without template-arguments.

But also

```
f.~foo(); // valid
```

Because `3.4.5 Class member access`:

```
3 If the unqualified-id is ˜type-name, and the type of the object expression
  is of a class type C (or of pointer to a class type C), the type-name is
  looked up in the context of the entire postfix-expression and in the scope of
  class C. [...]
```

thus in  `f.~foo();`, `foo` is looked up within `f.`, and *within* the scope of `foo<int>`, it is valid
to refer to it just with with `foo`.

---

### The standard is actually explicit on this topic, d'oh.

And finally, 14.3 contains the one-and-for-all-permission:

```
5   An explicit destructor call (12.4) for an object that 
    has a type that is a class template specialization may
    explicitly specify the template-arguments. [Example:

      template<class T> struct A {
          ˜A();
      };
      void f(A<int>* p, A<int>* q) {
          p->A<int>::˜A();      // OK: destructor call
          q->A<int>::˜A<int>(); // OK: destructor call
      }

    —end example]
```

Answer (score 3):

From n3290, 3.4.5 Class member access [basic.lookup.classref]

> 3 If the unqualified-id is ~type-name, the type-name is looked up in
>   the context of the entire postfix-expression. If the type T of the
>   object expression is of a class type C, the type-name is also looked
>   up in the scope of class C. At least one of the lookups shall find a
>   name that refers to (possibly cv-qualified) T. [...]

Following that is an example (as a non-normative note) which contains the following snippet of code:

```
a->~A(); // OK: lookup in *a finds the injected-class-name
```

In particular, for `template<typename T, typename Allocator> class vector;`, `vector` is the injected-class-name. For that reason, I believe

```
obj->v.~vector();
```

is correct.

(I don't have anything to say about `~vector<T>` <s>at the moment.</s>)

Comment: Could you add that the "injected name" includes namespaces?

Comment: @Kerrek That's what class scope means, I think. If that's not what you meant, notify me in chat if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following syntax it works in gcc as well:

```
obj->v.template ~vector<T>();
```

[Demo](http://www.ideone.com/44fCg).

Comment: That code says "dear compiler, please lookup the template `~vector<>`", but the OP does not define a templated destructor.